# Simultaneously vanishing quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms

Given a set of Hermitian matrices $\{A_i\}$, is there a simple way to check if there exists a vector $c$ such that for all $i$:

$$c^* A_i c = 0?$$

Namely, when can the quadratic forms defined by the $\{A_i\}$ simultaneously vanish?

Comment: Conceptually you're just checking the intersection of the radicals of the forms... but I guess that isn't concrete enough?

Comment: probably not. Also, if the number of $A_i$ is at least the dimension $n,$ then you do not expect any nonzero $c.$ Why do you want to do this?

Comment: If such $c$ exists then it should necessarily satisfy $c^*\sum_{k=1}^nx_kA_k c=0$ for all $x$. If there exists such $x$ that $\sum_{k=1}^nx_kA_k$ is positive definite then $c=0$. Finding $x$ is a semidefinite programming.

Comment: Do you mean $c^HA_ic=0$ by $c^*A_ic=0$? ($(\cdot)^H$ is the Hermitian operator)

Answer (score 2):

The system of equations you present is a quadratic system of polynomial equations for the components of $c$.  As discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_polynomial_equations), you can compute the Gröbner basis for this system of equations, which will tell you if it is inconsistent or not.  In order to exclude the zero vector as a solution you could add a normalization condition $c^* c = 1$.  I think this should work.

Comment: Few remarks. 1. We may assume that the $A_1,\cdots, A_k\in S_n$ constitute a free system. 2. See if there is $(j,k)$ s.t. the $(A_i)_{j,k}$ are zero. 3. Don't add the normalization condition $c^*c=1$ -that increases the calculation time of Grobner basis-  4. Indeed, it is better to calculate the Hilbert dimension $h$ of the Grobner basis; if $h>0$, then there is a non-zero solution. 5. If you want a calculation time <2', then you will have to settle for $n \leq 9$.

Comment: NB. Calculations are carried out for real symmetric matrices. For complex hermitian matrices it is more complicated.